# Invisible text in Markdown syntax help

Tags: bug, status-completed, meta, design

Some text is invisible in the **How to Format** help block because of a bad combination of text and background color:

[image]

That's meant to read

> ► backtick escapes `` `like _so_` ``

but the backquoted portion is nearly invisible (white text on light gray background).

How to reproduce the bug:

1. Go to the [Ask Question](https://stackapps.com/questions/ask) page.
2. Click in the body textarea. The box with the invisible text should appear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This design issue has been fixed in the **How to Format** section.

Currently the text is visible correctly:

> ► backtick escapes `` `like _so_` ``

Screenshot for reference:

[image: How to Format]